# make parallel completion barrier

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile with a target with several jobs running is parallel with `-j` option.

```
all: header
    mkdir -p $(STAGEDIR)
    @echo STAGEDIR = $(STAGEDIR)
    [ -z "$(dir_1_y)" ] || $(MAKE) -j$(HOST_NCPU) $(sort $(dir_1_y)) || exit $$?
    [ -z "$(dir_1_y)" ] || $(SET_STAGEDIR)
    [ -z "$(dir_2_y)" ] || $(MAKE) -j$(HOST_NCPU) $(sort $(dir_2_y)) || exit $$?
    [ -z "$(dir_2_y)" ] || $(SET_STAGEDIR)
```

The jobs may take different time to complete. Is there any way I can ensure that all of them are **done** before proceeding to the next stage in the build process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current recipe, all the jobs are done before the next line starts.  Whether or not `-j` is used is completely irrelevant.

Also, I don't know if you are aware, that what you have, is not a makefile.  It is really a shell script disguised as a makefile, with no advantages of using Make at all.  There is no reason to keep it that way.

Just forget about the "makefile" and use the shell script:

```
mkdir -p $STAGEDIR
echo STAGEDIR = $(STAGEDIR)
[ -z "$(dir_1_y)" ] || make -j$HOST_NCPU $(sort $dir_1_y) || exit $?
[ -z "$(dir_1_y)" ] || $(SET_STAGEDIR) 
[ -z "$(dir_2_y)" ] || $(MAKE) -j$HOST_NCPU $(sort $dir_2_y) || exit $?
[ -z "$(dir_2_y)" ] || $(SET_STAGEDIR)
```

When you do this, everything will be easier to manage, including matters like in your original question.  Make gives you specific advantages, at the cost of increased difficulty compared to shell script.  If you don't use the advantages at all, there is no point in coping with the difficulties.

Comment: Yes, it is a mix of shell and make. It is the old build system that I inherited. Trying to figure out why some parts proceed while others haven't finished yet.

Comment: There is not a chance that one line does not finish and next one starts.  Like I told you, think of it as a shell script, everything will be easier.

Comment: thanks. The failure looks like some parts start before they should. It just means that this error is somewhere else in the bowl of spaghetti.

Comment: Hmmm. Personally I would always prefer _make_ over _sh_ for building. Properly written makefiles are clearer and more importantly, easier to maintain IMHO. But there lies the rub: many people are familiar with the shell and do too much in the recipes, rather than using the _make_ idiom.

Comment: @bobbogo I do too prefer make.  I never said otherwise.  I just said, if you are not using make advantages, then there is no point of using make and it is better to use sh.

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking at too high a level.
*Make* prefers you just to give it true file based dependencies,
and it will accurately do what is asked of it.

So for example you may think of your build like this:

- Build libs
- Compile app objects
- Create executable by linking app objects and libs

Simples.
Thing is, the barriers here are artificial.
There is no reason why you can't be compiling one of the lib objects,
while *at the same time* compiling one of the app objects.
Or compiling some app objects while the libraries are being created.

Fine-grained dependencies are your friend.

```
${objects}: %.o: %.c ; Recipe for creating $@ from $<
lib1.a: l1.o l2.o ; Recipe for creating lib out of objects
lib2.a: l3.o l4.o ; Recipe for creating lib out of objects
executable: lib1.a lib2.a o5.o ; Recipe for linking
```

Here we have actual files as the dependencies and targets.
Maximum parallelism, error checking, and culled work.
This is a noddy example,
but consider a larger system where the build includes running tests.
When you make a change you only want to re-run a small subset of tests.
You also want to run some tests while other code is compiling.

Yes, you do have to get your dependencies right,
but that is the whole point of *make*.
If you can't do that, then yes, use a batch file and build from scratch every time.